Individual tree segmentation using watershed algorithm with lidR package
i am trying to use the watershed algorithm for individual tree segmentation, an embedded function watershed() in EBImage was recruited. However the function cannot ready my CHM and returns an error Error in validImage(x) : object must be an array. the code are as follows:
#read las file
las <- readLAS("440882004002000103501 - Cloud.las")

#ground points classification
lasgd <- classify_ground(las, algorithm = pmf(ws = 5, th = 0.5))

#digital terrain model (DTM)
dtm_kriging <- rasterize_terrain(lasgd, algorithm = kriging(k = 40)) #kriging

#Height normalization
nlas <- lasgd - dtm_kriging #dtm based

#DSM&CHM
chm <- rasterize_canopy(nlas, res = 0.20, algorithm = p2r(),pkg = "terra")
fill.na <- function(x, i=5) { if (is.na(x)[i]) { return(mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) } else { return(x[i]) }}
w <- matrix(1, 3, 3)
chm<- terra::focal(chm, w, fun = fill.na)
chm<- terra::focal(chm, w, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)

#Individual tree segmentation
algo <-watershed(chm)
> Error in validImage(x) : object must be an array
lasseg <- segment_trees(nlas, algo)

